# Read lines from a file and write to multiple PDFs doesn't work

Tags: c#, pdf, foreach

So I am trying to read a file line by line and write them to multiple PDFs, each PDF file should only contain 50 lines, if one PDF is full then another will be created until all lines are finished.

I almost finished it. But the problem is every time only the first PDF has contents. The others are all empty. Here is my code.

```
if ((System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Coil master 28-02-2019.csv")) == true)
{
    int lineNumber = 1;
    int PDFNumber = 0;
    for (; PDFNumber < 4; PDFNumber++)
    {
        string path = Application.StartupPath;
        var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(2976, 4194);

        Document pdfdoc = new Document(pgSize); // Setting the page size for the PDF
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, new FileStream(path + "/MasterCoils/" + (1 + (50 * PDFNumber)) + "-" + (50 + (PDFNumber * 50)) + ".pdf", FileMode.Create)); //Using the PDF Writer class to generate the PDF
        pdfdoc.Open(); // Opening the PDF to write the data from the textbox

        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Coil master 28-02-2019.csv").Skip(1 + (50 * PDFNumber)).Take(50))
        {
                string[] inputArray = line.Split(delimiters); // split the input string by using the delimiter ','

                COILID = inputArray[0];
                TYPE = inputArray[1];
                COLOR = inputArray[2];
                WEIGHT = Int32.Parse(inputArray[3]);
                GAUGE = inputArray[4];
                WIDTH = inputArray[5];

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                // we tell the ContentByte we're ready to draw text
                cb.BeginText();

                // set up Font and Size for Content to be shown in PDF
                BaseFont mybf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                cb.SetFontAndSize(mybf, 15);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(250 + (595 * i), (419 * (9 - j)) + 280);
                cb.ShowText(COILID + "+" + TYPE + "+" + COLOR + "+" + WEIGHT + "+" + GAUGE + "+" + WIDTH);

                // we tell the contentByte, we've finished drawing text
                cb.EndText();

                lineNumber++;
        }

        pdfdoc.Close();
    }
}
```

If I delete the foreach statement, then all PDFs would have some contents. So I guess the problem is from the foreach, but I couldn't find exactly where is wrong. Please give me some help. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what's specifically wrong here, except to say that you have your loops in a rather backward arrangement. The way you're doing it now definitely won't scale well. Instead of reading the CSV from the beginning and skipping to the new starting point every time you start a new PDF file, open the CSV file once, then: start a new PDF file, read (up to) 50 lines from the CSV, write the lines to the PDF, close the PDF... if there are more lines, start a new PDF, read, write, close PDF, repeat.

Comment: Is this your real code? Your foreach loop assigns to the variable `line` but it's value is never used.

Comment: Looks like there’s some other code somewhere. I see variables i, j and lineNumber but I don’t know where they come from... you should post the whole code, considering that te problem might be right in that area...

Comment: Your loop works. Your problem lays elsewhere

Comment: Indeed, the code as is either won't compile or (if one creates the missing variables with a constant value) would draw all outputs at the identical position.

Comment: @madreflection After some tests, I guess the problem is because ReadLines opens a process in the background and when the for loop hit this ReadLines the second time, it won't let me to read the same file because the process is still running. So the way to solve it is to only open the CSV file once. But I am not sure how to do it. Could you give me some help?

Comment: @yuancheng - I gave you the general algorithm in my first comment. Thing is, you can't ever *expect* to be sure in programming. Actually *being* "sure" comes with experience. Until then, you start by doing and when that doesn't work, you start again by redoing, and you always try to learn something on each iteration. If you want to try my suggestion, you'll be starting over, throwing away code (or just moving it to a separate editor for safe keeping). That's normal. Don't get too attached to code that doesn't work. Just break it down and take it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code and it works exactly as expected, reads a csv and makes 4 new PDF's all containing data.

The only thing I really changed was the way the PDF's were being written to.

I am not an ITextSharp expert but I hope this helps you.

```
if (File.Exists(@"Coil master 28-02-2019.csv") == true)
{
    int fileNumber = 0;

    for (; fileNumber < 4; fileNumber++)
    {
        var pgSize = new Rectangle(2976, 4194);

        var pdfdoc = new Document(pgSize); // Setting the page size for the PDF

        pdfdoc.Open(); // Opening the PDF to write the data from the textbox

        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("Coil master 28-02-2019.csv").Skip(1 + (50 * fileNumber)).Take(50))
        {
            string[] inputArray = line.Split(','); // split the input string by using the delimiter ','

            var COILID = inputArray[0];
            var TYPE = inputArray[1];
            var COLOR = inputArray[2];
            var WEIGHT = Int32.Parse(inputArray[3]);
            var GAUGE = inputArray[4];
            var WIDTH = inputArray[5];

            var p = new Paragraph(COILID + "+" + TYPE + "+" + COLOR + "+" + WEIGHT + "+" + GAUGE + "+" + WIDTH);
            pdfdoc.Add(p);
        }

        pdfdoc.Close();
    }
}
```